# Nested asynchronous axios calls only returns one object

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

Been stuck with this one for over an hour now so can someone point me in the right direction?

In my code snippet below I only get back one object instead of multiple objects.

I explained the issue quite detailed with comments between my code snippet, so the problem should be clear.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('url-here').then((res) => {
      res.data.favProperties?.map((el) => {
        console.log(el) // this returns id's of saved/liked items
        axios.get('url-here').then(async (r) => {
          if (r.data) {
            console.log(r.data) // Problem starts here
            // This returns the full object of the liked items
            // But only one object is returned, not every object for which an id was stored
            await storageRef
              .child(r.data.firebaseRef + '/' + r.data.images[0])
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => {
                // Here i need to fetch the image for each object
                console.log(url)
              })
              .catch((err) => console.log(err))
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }, [])
```

Thanks for looking into it!
Kind regards

Comment: This isn't really a [mcve] -- why not simplify and mock the axios calls for demonstration purposes to show the underlying pattern, then extrapolate back to your original code? Very likely, you want `Promise.all` and don't combine `async`/`await` and `then`. I'd just use `async`/`await`.

Comment: what does it mean that "only one object is returned"?  returned to where?  is your API supposed to return multiple objects?

Comment: @DanO yes exactly. For each `id` stored in `res.data.favProperties` an object should return. The problem is that I dont know how to implement a `promise.all()` here ...

Comment: @ggorlen If `promise.all()` is the solution here, what would be the way to implement it?

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), is built into JS so you can use it on `map` calls that return promises -- please provide a simplified version of the code as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so I don't have to guess about whether my blind rearrangement of your code works or not. Please mock out the API calls to show the responses we're working with here and I'd be happy to offer a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen i'm sorry but i don't really know how to rewrite my problem here... My api calls run on localhost so i can not reproduce that. Like i show in my code snippet: at the first `res.data.favProperties?.map` i fetch the `id's` of all items that the user liked. Then for each `id` i want to fetch that item from the database (based on that id). But as my code is written currently it only takes the first one or the last one (i guess) because my code isn't written corrrectly asynchronously. I don't know how to write my problem as it is now